# Xcode ARC project is added dealloc with release calls

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I converted my project to use ARC, but when I add items to a xib and then drag them over to my .h file to create IBOutlets, Xcode adds the dealloc method again with release calls and a `[super dealloc]` call.

I don't want to have to remove these things every time I add an outlet in this project. What's causing this?

Comment: I assume that by now you have fixed this problem - did you ever find the root of the problem?

Comment: No, I haven't. It is still happening. :(

Comment: There was another post where someone was getting really bizarre stuff. The closed the project and maybe Xcode, then from terminal rm -rf on these two directories: ./project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<your id>.xcuserdatad
./xcuserdata/<your id>.xcuserdatad - its probably worth a shot. Also, look in your Build Phase, at the compile flags - any set to non-arc that should not be?

Comment: It also occurred to me that you should delete your "Derived Data" folder - that's a likely place for Xcode to have cached some setting. You can find it by looking in the Xcode Organizer, Projects pane. I'd close the project before blowing that away, then open the project, then build and test. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Did you close the project and reopen it after converting? This sounds like one of those stale data things in Xcode. After you do this, then check both the project settings and target settings to be sure that ARC is in fact enabled.

I never saw this after converting my projects, but am 100% sure that I closed/reopened first. I DID see other bizarre stuff after changing so now in habit to close/reopen.

EDIT: Also, select the xib file, then open the rightmost pane and look at the "Interface Builder Document" section, and make sure that the Deployment and Development versions are the newest.

Comment: Did you check both the project, and the target, to be sure BOTH have ARC enabled???

Answer (score 1):

I've experiences this previously. I had different targets - which was not all set to ARC.

Check if the eg. Release settings is set to non-ARC. If some build configations on some targets have ARC enabled, I believe Xcode will make dealloc methods when dragging from XIBs.

Comment: I've verified that my build settings only have one value for ARC and it is set to Yes.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem. My main target was ARC but two unused targets were not ARC enabled.